# For neo4j community edition on windows，Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version

Tags: neo4j

I use the neo4j community edition on windows to see a database.
The path of database is D:\Alamgir\neo4jdb.
When start it shows:

> Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version.
>   To enable automatic upgrade, please set   configuration parameter   "allow_store_upgrade=true"

I update the parameter on neo4j.properties and neo4j.conf just like this:

[image]

But it still doesn't work .What can I do? Help~

Comment: So did you uncomment the line ? Also what version of neo4j are you running ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to **uncomment** the line in the config file, i.e. remove the preceding `#`:

```
allow_store_upgrade=true
```

Comment: And by "uncommenting", Martin means removing the preceding `#`.

Comment: Thank you so much！